# Django - How to do an if statement if button is clicked

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement, button

I want the user to click a button on my website, and when it is clicked I want i = i + 1.
So far I have this code that doesn't work

```
 # On html file
<form method='get' action='#'>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="Next"/>
</form>

# In django views
    if request.GET.get('Name'):
        print('user clicked summary')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try -

```
# On html file
<form method='get' action='#'>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="Next"/>
</form>

# In django views
    if request.GET.get('Next') == 'Next':
        print('user clicked summary')
```

Because the name of the button is `'Next'` not `'Name'`