# django use html selected as if/else selection in views

Tags: ajax, select, django-views

thanks in advance

I'm new to web development and I'm task to do this Django project.

I had Selection the user will select one and tells the views which chose to use (if & else if)

then the view Query the data from DB and will return to HTML

I try using this following this answer: [Django - How to do an if statement if button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911264/django-how-to-do-an-if-statement-if-button-is-clicked)

but run into this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ph-data/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'zigview']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  157.         context = self.get_context_data()

File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Frouniter\FrounterWeb- postgreDB\zigview\views.py" in get_context_data
  46.             if request.GET.get('Week') == 'Week':

Exception Type: NameError at /ph-data/
Exception Value: name 'request' is not defined
```

I move to seconds solution which is to use ajax, but the more Look at ajax the more lost i'm am.

Here my views codes:

```
try:
    class index(ListView):
        model = tank_system
        template_name = 'FrounterWeb/extends/includes.html'
        ordering = ['-datetime']

        def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
            return{'tank':self.get_queryset()}
        #def get_queryset(self):
         #   return

except:
    logger.error('index page request failed/errors')


try:
    class ph(ListView):
        model = tank_system
        template_name = 'FrounterWeb/extends/ph.html'
        context_object_name = tank_system
        ordering = ['-datetime'] # sort dates in descending order

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            ###################### Days filter #################################
            today_date = datetime.now().day#call today datas
            yesterday_date = datetime.now().day - 1
            ###################### end of Days filter ###########################


            ############################# Weeks Filter ######################
            # last week math caluactions
            some_day_last_week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
            monday_of_last_week = some_day_last_week - timedelta(days=(some_day_last_week.isocalendar()[2] - 1))
            monday_of_this_week = monday_of_last_week + timedelta(days=7)
            # last week math caluactions

            #this week data
            monday_of_next_week = monday_of_this_week + timedelta(days=7)
            Thisweekdata = {'tank': self.get_queryset().filter(datetime__gte=monday_of_this_week, datetime__lt=monday_of_next_week)}
            ############################# Weeks Filter ######################


            ###################### Months filter ###########################
            currentMonth = datetime.now().month #take this months
            pastMonth = currentMonth - 1
            ###################### end of Months filter ###########################

            ###################### Year filter ###########################
            currentYear = datetime.now().year
            lastYear = currentYear - 1
            ###################### end of Year filter ###########################

            #if case
            return {'tank': self.get_queryset()}
except:
    logger.error('PH page Functions failed/errors')


try:
    class EC(ListView):
        model = tank_system
        template_name = 'FrounterWeb/extends/EC.html'
        ordering = ['-datetime']  # sort dates in descending order

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            return {'tank': self.get_queryset()}
except:
    logger.error('EC page Functions failed/errors')
```

Questions Summary:

1. Need to send get the request to back end
2. The request got to back end and it will see which data should go out
3. return the selected/filter data (week, day etc)

Here a picture for better understanding:
[image: understanding use]
I'm Sorry to ask something this simple, and thank you

Comment: You should post your `zigview/views.py` file.